# Having a section have it's own scroll bar

Tags: html, css

I want to make a vertical scroll bar for a small section. Here's an example:

HTML:

```
<content class="main">
    <h3 class="news">News</h3>
</content>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: teal;
}

.main {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #00dddd;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.news {
  max-height: 40%;
}
```

How do I keep the section to not overflow past 50% when I just spam this:

```
<content class="main">
  <h3 class="news">News</h3>
  <h3 class="news">News</h3>
  <h3 class="news">News</h3>
  <h3 class="news">News</h3>
  <h3 class="news">News</h3>
  <h3 class="news">News</h3>
  <h3 class="news">News</h3>
  <h3 class="news">News</h3>
  <h3 class="news">News</h3>
</content>
```

Similarly to how the Stack Overflow gave a horizontal scroll bar after I put too many h3 elements for it to fit on one page, how would I do the same for a vertical scroll bar?

Comment: Please don't use `<content>`  it's obsolete - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/content

Comment: look into css overflow

Answer (score 0):

Just give `width: 100%; height: 100%;` to `html` and `body` if you want to use `width` and `height` for child elements in percents. You also should specify `max-height: 40%;` for `<content class="main">` element, not for child `<h3 class="news">`. And don't forget to add `overflow-y: auto;` to `content` element, it will add vertical scroll when it's needed. Here is an example:

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: teal;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #00dddd;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  max-height: 40% !important;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<content class="main">
  <h3 class="news">News</h3>
  <h3 class="news">News</h3>
  <h3 class="news">News</h3>
  <h3 class="news">News</h3>
  <h3 class="news">News</h3>
  <h3 class="news">News</h3>
  <h3 class="news">News</h3>
  <h3 class="news">News</h3>
  <h3 class="news">News</h3>
</content>
```